# Optimize MySQL InnoDB query for max, count

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, innodb

I have an MySQL InnoDB table with 5.7M rows and 1.9GB size:

```
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|       Field       |  Type   | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| listing_id        | int(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| listing_link      | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| transaction_title | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image_thumb       | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| seller_link       | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| seller_name       | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sale_date         | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here are my my.ini settings for my 3GB RAM server:

```
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0
join_buffer_size = 8M
thread_cache_size = 8
thread_concurrency = 8
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_limit = 2M
ft_min_word_len = 4
thread_stack = 192K
tmp_table_size = 64M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
innodb_write_io_threads = 8
innodb_read_io_threads = 8
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
```

When I run next query it takes over 20 minutes to return the results:

```
SELECT transaction_title, 
       listing_id, 
       seller_name, 
       Max(sale_date) AS sale_date, 
       Count(*)       AS count 
FROM   sales_meta 
WHERE `sale_date` BETWEEN '2017-06-06' AND '2017-06-06' 
GROUP  BY listing_id 
HAVING Count(*) > 1 
ORDER  BY count DESC, 
          seller_name;
```

I've done some research and it appears I need to add some indexes to speed things up, but I am confused how to go about it. There are some single-column indexes and some multi-column indexes, which one should I do?

To make things more complicated, there are few other queries that I will need to perform on this table regularly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   sales_meta 
WHERE ` sale_date `= '2017-06-06';
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT `seller_name` 
FROM   `sales_meta`;
```

These two are probably less taxing, but I still need to optimize for them as well if possible, although the first query out of three is the top priority for now.

Comment: . . Your query is malformed.  Your `select` contains several unaggregated columns that are not in the `group by`.  Fix the query before optimizing it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you please show what the correct query structure would look like for this query, maybe as an answer below?

Comment: . . I don't know what you are trying to do, so, no I can't.  I can say that the unaggregated columns in the `select` all should be in the `group by`.

Comment: That is, you will be getting a random title and name since you are not grouping by them, too.

Comment: @Acidon Please post text results of SHOW INDEX FROM sales_meta > SIFsales-meta.txt; and tell us if ANY of the 3 queries are still 'slow'. If the first one is performing well, you should be able to use your BETWEEN rather than only EQUAL and have excellent performance. How much RAM do you have? Do you use any SSD/NVME for data storage? What is result of SELECT @@version; Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want just the value for a single day and the the data type is date then you could avoid the between  clause  and use =

```
    SELECT transaction_title, 
           listing_id, 
           seller_name, 
           Max(sale_date) AS max_sale_date, 
           Count(*)       AS count 
    FROM   sales_meta 
    WHERE sale_date =  str_to_date('2017-06-06', '%Y-%m-%d')  
    GROUP  BY listing_id 
    HAVING Count(*) > 1 
    ORDER  BY count DESC, seller_name;
```

and  be sure you have an index  on  sale_date

Comment: Does your use of  `str_to_date` here provide any benefit?

Comment: @scaisEdge I do use this query for both single day and date range cases, if there is a performance benefit to get rid of BETWEEN clause for single date look-ups I will be sure to implement it.

Comment: I'm not in you data contents  so you should try and based on the result eval if my suggestion are useful or not  .. .. there is not a single solution for all the performance problem .. sometimes  one solutione resolve one problem bute create others so .. you should eval  step by step

Comment: @WillemRenzema   should not  .. because for default format the conversion should be done by mysql  .. but is usually use the explicit conversione for avoid  illegal date problem ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Ok, thanks. I was worried there for a moment that I was inadvertently slowing down my own queries by not using `str_to_date`.

Comment: Adding index on `sale_date` boosted speed to 0.2 seconds vs previous 22 minutes! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Looks like the index on `sale_date` is definitely something you should add as a couple of queries in the question use `sale_date`
- Another suggestion is to index the column used in `GROUP BY` as per MySQL's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html)

Instead of following an approach of adding all the indices in one go, I would opt for incremental approach and measure the performance after adding each index.

Comment: Unfortunately, indexing column used in GROUP BY did not bring any performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(sale_date) -- very important for the first query

str_to_date('2017-06-06', '%Y-%m-%d') -- no better than '2017-06-06'

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G  -- too big for your tiny RAM; change to 1G (swapping kills perf)

GROUP  BY listing_id  -- meaningless, since `listing_id` is unique; hence count is always 1

Prefer using an explicit list instead of `SELECT *`

SELECT DISTINCT `seller_name` 
    FROM   `sales_meta`;       -- needs INDEX(seller_name)

but `seller_name` needs to be a VARCHAR, not TEXT
```

Further evidence that `str_to_date` is useless:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-27', '%Y-%m-%d');
+---------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-27', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2019-02-27                            |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `listing_id` is not unique - there could by many sales of product with given listing_id each day. The whole point of the query is to show how many times each product been sold in a given period of time. I will look into other suggestions though, thanks!